# Web Formulario Modal C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal

quisiera preguntar... ¿Es posible crear un formulario modal y abrirlo desde un formulario, sin que el proyecto esté construido en MVC (C#)?... He consultado como poner ventanas modales, y he encontrado contenido sobre las vistas, pero la mayoría de tutoriales ya tienen el proyecto en modelo MVC y pues parten desde ahí con el tutorial, creando en el controlador y luego la vista.

Sin embargo mi proyecto no está en MVC, y lo tengo de la siguiente manera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que cuando no encuentre un paciente, pueda abrir desde el botón "Acciones", un formulario modal para poder agregarlo, editarlo, o anularlo. No lo como hacerlo sin tener el proyecto en MVC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco sus comentarios y su ayuda.

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude: [asp-net-web-forms-modal-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591792/asp-net-web-forms-modal-form)

Comment: Saludos @Arriel intenté copiar ese código para acondicionarlo al proyecto, sin embargo no me abre la ventana modal, y los archivos que dice en el ejemplo se deben incluir no lo encuentro en la pagina de JQuery, agrego la ultima versión minificada, pero igual no me funciona el modal...

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos un poco de tu código para revisarlo? Más específicamente el html y el javascript?